# .Net Core Identity Login Page is not working hosted application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

This is my first time hosting a .net core application on Server IIS. after publishing the application on IIS it is working fine. when I go to the login page and after entering the user credentials, it gives me the following page. (It is working fine locally)
What is the problem?

Also for the database in code first approach, Am I creating the database and restoring the backup on it or there is a way to run the migration and seed data?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding the following line to project file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>    
</PropertyGroup>
```